# Search in Pandas for first instance of condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a panda table where I am trying to look backwards from a certain row for the index of a condition.

```
Index    column1    column2
0         True       False
1         True       False
2         False      False
3         True       False
4         False      False
5         False      False
6         False      True
7         False      True
```

So given the above table.
I know the index of column2 and am using that so I have 6
now I want to look back and then find the first instance of a different column changing (column1)
In this case it would return 3

Is there a good efficient way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `shift` with `idxmax`

```
df.column1.ne(df.column1.shift().bfill()).idxmax()+1
Out[86]: 3
```